# CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedDayNames problem

Tags: .net, windows, windows-phone-7

I tried googling it but nothing came out. My problem is that for EN-GB CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedDayNames begins with Sun for Sunday when for that culture FirstDayOfWeek is Monday?! I need a way to get AbbreviatedDayNames so that they correspond to FirstDayOfWeek. Otherwise my calendar app for WP7 won't work properly.

UPDATE: This is how I get it now:

```
        DayOfWeek firstDay = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
        AbbreviatedDayNames = new List<string>();

        for (int i = (int)firstDay; i < 7; i++)
        {
            AbbreviatedDayNames.Add(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedDayNames[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)firstDay; i++)
        {
            AbbreviatedDayNames.Add(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedDayNames[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to MSDN, this property array will always contain the 7 values starting with "Sun":

> A one-dimensional array of type String
>   containing the culture-specific
>   abbreviated names of the days of the
>   week. The array for InvariantInfo
>   contains "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed",
>   "Thu", "Fri", and "Sat".

It looks like this array is indexed using the DayOfWeek enum - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx

You'll need to build a simple lookup yourself from the current FirstDayOfWeek-indexed week to the fixed abbreviated array

Comment: How silly, both me for not checking and the way AbbrevieatedNames work. Thanks Stuart.